# Type guard for array element's "possibly undefined" error

Tags: arrays, typescript, undefined, typeguards

TSC gives an error which is added as a comment in to code.

tsconfig: `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true`

```
type Tfactors = [number, number, number, number];

export default function changeEnough(pocket: Tfactors, bill: number): boolean {
  const coinToDolarFactors: Tfactors = [0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.01];
  let pocketTotal = 0;

  for (let i in pocket) {

    if (pocket[i] !== undefined && coinToDolarFactors[i] !== undefined) {
      //Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
      pocketTotal += pocket[i] * coinToDolarFactors[i];
    }
  }

  return pocketTotal >= bill;
}
```

I solved this problem like this:

```
type Tfactors = [number, number, number, number];

export default function changeEnough(pocket: Tfactors, bill: number): boolean {
  const coinToDolarFactors: Tfactors = [0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.01];
  let pocketTotal = 0;

  for (let i in pocket) {
    const pocketValue = pocket[i];
    const factor = coinToDolarFactors[i];
    if (pocketValue !== undefined && factor !== undefined) {
      pocketTotal += pocketValue * factor;
    }
  }

  return pocketTotal >= bill;
}
```

I am new on TypeScript and I do not know is this optimal way to solve this problem. Can I solve this problem without declaring `pocketValue`  and `factor` variables and without use `!` to mute TSC.

Comment: I don't see the issue in typescript playground.

Comment: "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgZgQwMbAPYCcDOUC8UDaAdgK4C2ARhOgDRQkVW32U11ksC6A3AFA8QAPMBmBQAJhETEANqLjFCKAJapCUJAAsEhAOYQAooVTEdGgBTCkAawjAAXLEQoMmWuSXTpD5lQCUD8lRUaQhtKABvHih1VUxRJFQlQhhUABFghHQAMWQ0LAd4XJdcAgAGADoAJgBWWgqARjry2qgK0vruKKgQ0UsbYBTgBGkS0t4uuAwoMx6oJTm1PttfCL5o6KU4aaXgfCUOKABCHDwFCTgkiDEoADIbmKSU9OlMnOcsPYPj08Jzy7EVpF1usAPQggDy5AAVhAUHNsMJMJglORpCAoAByM6Sf4Y8rATBmGoAZkqvi6wJ2g2GUAA1Hgdp8oAAqB7JNIZbJFD77XjAgC+XUFXXQtmI6EWqGstmpIwAfHh3J5ePygA

Comment: typescript does not go that deep to type guard `pocket[i]` and `coinToDolarFactors[i]`, so inside the `if `block, it loses the context of that type guard. That said, your approach of using `const` works well since TS knows for certain it is undefined with `const` assignments; alternatively, you can `for (let _i in pocket) { const i =  _i as '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'; ...}`, given `Tfactors` is a tuple type.

Comment: @ABOS    as '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'  is kind of hard code. But I already define a tuple. why tuple does not guarantee that index is in range?

Comment: `Exclude<keyof Tfactors, keyof []>` gives `'0'|'1'|'2'|'3'` which can be used to remove hardcoded type.

Comment: But this is what actually `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` does. Why did You enable it, if it's not needed/useful in Your case?

Comment: @TomaszGawel what can I do. must I create different tsconfig files for every .ts files in the project?  I just make true all strict rules to make code more "stabile".

Comment: @mustafa kemal tuna Why not just set `noUncheckedIndexedAccess: false` in your tsconfig?

Comment: Tangentially related: please do not use `for...in` to iterate over arrays, there are dedicated methods for array traversal (at least use `for...of`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `!` to mute TSC or assign array elements to new variables, you can explicitly type array index, i.e.

```
type Tfactors = [number, number, number, number];

export default function changeEnough(pocket: Tfactors, bill: number): boolean {
  const coinToDolarFactors: Tfactors = [0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.01];
  let pocketTotal = 0;

  for (let _i in pocket) {
    /* --  type it explicitly here -- */
    let i = _i as Exclude<keyof Tfactors, keyof []>;
    // *if* check is not required if you are confident they are defined at runtime  
    if (pocket[i] !== undefined && coinToDolarFactors[i] !== undefined) {
      //Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
      pocketTotal += pocket[i] * coinToDolarFactors[i];
    }
  }

  return pocketTotal >= bill;
}
```

Comment: It is still weird and kind of manual touch like ! operator but this answer fits to the question. Thank you.

Comment: I see it extremely ugly ;) - and to me, it stands in contradition to goal of using typescript - e.g. project maintainabilty. In my humble opinion `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` should be `false` by default.

Comment: @TomaszGawel, `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is still very useful in most cases, and it should not be disabled simply because it does not cover some `corner` cases. Perhaps future version of typescript will improve type checking on such scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

From the doc [Pedantic Index Signature Checks (--noUncheckedIndexedAccess)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access), we know

> One consequence of using `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is that indexing into an array is also more strictly checked, even in a bounds-checked loop.

> Under this new mode, every property access (like `foo.bar`) or indexed access (like `foo["bar"]`) is considered potentially `undefined`.

solution:

If you need to access that property, you’ll either have to check for its existence first or use a non-null assertion operator (the postfix ! character).

```
// Checking if it's really there first.
const pocketValue = pocket[i];
const factor = coinToDolarFactors[i];
if (pocketValue !== undefined && factor !== undefined) {
  pocketTotal += pocketValue * factor;
}


// Basically saying "trust me I know what I'm doing"
// with the '!' non-null assertion operator.
pocketTotal += pocket[i]! * coinToDolarFactors[i]!;
```

Comment: Thank you for information. But first one of your solution is already in the question and the other one is excluded by question.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I solve this problem without declaring pocketValue and factor variables [or] without use ! to mute TSC.

No, you cannot, unfortunately.